# API can't use Integer Variable but static Integer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, api

I am using an API and I'm not able to bind an Integer Variable into it. I will attach my script below, but a little explanation can't hurt: Another script filters data that is send via curl, most of this data are strings, but the API forces this one to be Integer.

```
curl \
--data '{"version":"2.0",
"method":"cmdb.object.create",
"params":{"type":"C__OBJTYPE__VIRTUAL_SERVER",
"title":"'"${name}"'",
"categories":{"C__CATG__IP": [ { "ipv4_address" : "'"${ip}"'" }  ],
"C__CATG__VIRTUAL_MACHINE__ROOT": [ { "hosts": $host, "description" : "'"${ops}"'"  } ]
},
"apikey":"apikey"},"id": 1 }' \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://someURL
```

Where name could be "VirtualMachine1", ipv4_address "1.2.3.4", host 736, ops "Windows 7".

The error code with this curl is: code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request : Provided request is not a valid json rpc."

It works if I just write a number instead of $host so I guess I just bind the variable wrong.

A valid and working request would be:

```
curl \
    --data '{"version":"2.0",
    "method":"cmdb.object.create",
    "params":{"type":"C__OBJTYPE__VIRTUAL_SERVER",
    "title":"'"${name}"'",
    "categories":{"C__CATG__IP": [ { "ipv4_address" : "'"${ip}"'" }  ],
    "C__CATG__VIRTUAL_MACHINE__ROOT": [ { "hosts": 123, "description" : "'"${ops}"'"  } ]
    },
    "apikey":"apikey"},"id": 1 }' \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://someURL
```

Comment: If I qoute it I get the error code: host-variable must be Integer, so that doesn't work either

Comment: As far as I can see, your `$host` is within *single* quotes. So it won't get expanded. Your JSON will just contain `$host` which is invalid. You have to do the same as you already to with `$ip`: replace `$host` by `'$host'` (to have `$host` outside of single quotes).

Comment: Solved! Thank you.